# Opencart Send Email to Multiple Groups

Tags: php, html, css, opencart

I would like to be able to modify Opencart's admin panel where you can select multiple groups instead of just 1 when sending emails to customers.

I don't know where and how to modify the system to do so as I'm still new to this kind of stuff.
[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Mail system in OpenCart lets you send emails to specific customer groups. Not all at the time.

You can use this feature to send newsletters, information on specials, or to communicate any type of store information to select groups of customers.

**NOTE:)**

1:) If You need **All Customers Groups** You can select **All Customers** Like following Screenshot.

2:) There is no need to Extra Customize for **All Customers Groups**.

3:) All customers Email send is One kind of **All Customers Groups**.

**SCREENSHOT:)**

[image]

Comment: I get that, but I've been assigned a task to be able to modify the selection where I can select multiple groups at once. I'm not sure it's possible or not as I have researched for days and unable to find any solutions to be able to do so.

Comment: @PineappleMig. If you need Customization. That's are possible. you can see my edited answer as well. You can contact me personally via Email and Linkedin at my Profiles Description.